# Full system simulation at Gem5, RISC-V

Tags: riscv, bare-metal, gem5

I want to run a 64-bit RISC-V binary without OS in gem5’s fs mode. I tried --kernel= but it didn’t stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a feature in the upcoming 21.0 release. See this Jira issue for the current status: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-367.